# What are the subject and predicate in the following sentences?

Tags: subjects, predicate

**1.** **Mercy on us.**

**2.** **Thank you, my dear friend**.

What are the subject and predicate in these two sentences?

Comment: What do _you_ think the subjects and predicates are?

Comment: Subject is a word or a group of words denoting a person or a thing spoken about in a sentence. And predicate is which says something about subject. BillJ

Comment: It might be considered that, linguistically, words are missing from each of the above. 'May mercy be toward us' and 'May thanks be unto you' perhaps add the invisible words.

Comment: @MdAsaduzzaman: Alas, those are not definitions of grammatical subject and predicate, as you have found, since they don't give you any good tests to use. All the words in a sentence are "spoken about", and they all "say something about subject". In fact, neither (1) nor (2) is a sentence, in ordinary use, and therefore there are no subjects or predicates, any more than there are with _Hello_ or _Hell!_.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. Such questions may be closed as lacking research effort until they are edited to include research. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, or putting substantial thought into the question on your own. See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there's an understood, "[God] have mercy on us" in the first sentence, making the subject "God" and the predicate "have mercy." In the second, there would be an understood, "[I] thank you," leaving us with "I" as the subject and "thank" as the predicate.